# attempt to index a boolean value (local 'user')

Tags: lua, boolean, fivem

I'm really stuck on this. When I try and buy something from my in game store it doesn't take money away from me and it says this in the console "SCRIPT ERROR: @shops/server.lua:71: attempt to index a boolean value (local 'user')"

Here is the script:

```
RegisterServerEvent('cash:remove')
AddEventHandler('cash:remove', function(src,amount)
    local user = exports["np-base"]:getModule("Player"):GetUser(src)
    user:removeMoney(tonumber(amount))
end)
```

I'm super confused and don't know how to fix this, any help would be great!

Comment: I have no idea what any of those functions do that you're calling, but `GetUser` must be returning a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`exports["np-base"]:getModule("Player"):GetUser(src)` is returning a nil value.

Hence`user:removeMoney(tonumber(amount))` is causing an error as you may not index boolean values. (true or false)

Find out why this function returns a boolean whhere you expect some user object and fix that. If it is ok for the function to return that make sure you don't index it. For example by using a conditional statement.